# IntelliJ IDEA xml configuration for built-in keymaps

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

Where can I find the IntelliJ IDEA xml configuration for the built-in keymaps like `Mac OS X` etc.?  When I export settings, only my custom keymaps are in the resulting xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can find them in the [IntelliJ IDEA source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/idea).

Comment: The latest place is https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/platform-resources/src/keymaps